# Selecting latest timestsamp based on column

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I have a query:

```
SELECT ti.*
FROM New_OTPMS.TBL_TESTER_ONLINE_INFO ti
INNER JOIN TBL_TESTER_LIST tl
ON ti.tester_name = tl.tester_name
WHERE ti.board_name = 'DC30'
AND tl.tester_type = 'UFLEX'
ORDER BY ti.tester_name
```

In the table table that I'm selecting from, `TBL_TESTER_ONLINE_INFO`, there is a column named `last_checked` where it has keeps the timestamp of the records. The timestamps are all different.

However in this table there is one column which can contain duplicated records which is `tester_name`. So I can have `test1` and `test1` but both with different timestamps.

Example:

```
tester_name       last_checked
   test1          2015-07-30 03:56:51
   test1          2015-07-31 05:56:38
   test2          2015-07-31 10:10:36
   test2          2015-07-31 02:27:12
```

I want to get the latest time stamp only. So an example of the output I want to get would be

```
tester_name       last_checked
   test1          2015-07-31 05:56:38
   test2          2015-07-31 02:27:12
```

I'm not sure how to modify the query I'm using, I've tried to `group by last_checked` but obviously that's the wrong way. I've seen other answers using inner joins

```
SELECT ti.*
FROM New_OTPMS.TBL_TESTER_ONLINE_INFO ti
INNER join
(
    SELECT id, max(last_checked) as mts
    FROM New_OTPMS.TBL_TESTER_ONLINE_INFO
    GROUP BY id
)  s2 on s2.id = ti.id and ti.last_checked = s2.mts
INNER JOIN TBL_TESTER_LIST tl
ON ti.tester_name = tl.tester_name
WHERE ti.board_name = 'DC30'
AND tl.tester_type = 'UFLEX'
ORDER BY ti.tester_name
```

but it returns the same rows (with duplicates) as the unmodified query.

Any help?

P.S. There are more columns to the table of course but the illustration is just to show a simple example in this question.

EDIT: TBL_TESTER_ONLINE_CONFIG Sample data

```
 id      tester_name        frame       board_name  config    part_no, serial_no, license_count, legal_enabling   last_checked             log_name
'105318' 'UFLEX-02' 'LICENSE_ENABLERS' 'DC30'     '1'       ' '      ' '        'N/A'          '1,0'          '2015-07-30 00:35:15' 'IGXLEventLog.7.30.2015.00.34.21.000.log'
'105048' 'UFLEX-02', 'LICENSE_ENABLERS' 'DC30'    '1'       ' '      ' '        'N/A'          '1,0'          '2015-07-29 15:31:42' 'IGXLEventLog.7.29.2015.15.30.46.344.log'
'109709' 'UFLEX-05', 'LICENSE_ENABLERS' 'DC30'    '1'       ' '      ' '        'N/A'          '1,0'          '2015-07-30 05:10:16' 'IGXLEventLog.7.30.2015.05.09.45.515.log'
'108802' 'UFLEX-05', 'LICENSE_ENABLERS' 'DC30'    '1'       ' '      ' '        'N/A'          '1,0'          '2015-07-30 01:34:08' 'IGXLEventLog.7.30.2015.01.33.36.891.log'
```

Ignore everythign except `tester_name` column and `last_checked` column. Just want to ensure I only get one tester name. I'm doing this for a web application (in PHP) to get specific testers, if that info helps.

Comment: provide some sample data

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid Edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly use `max(last_checked)` function to check latest timestamp and use `GROUP BY tester_name` so it will give you distinct value. Try below query :

```
SELECT ti.tester_name, MAX(ti.last_checked)
FROM New_OTPMS.TBL_TESTER_ONLINE_INFO ti
INNER JOIN TBL_TESTER_LIST tl
ON ti.tester_name = tl.tester_name
WHERE ti.board_name = 'DC30'
AND tl.tester_type = 'UFLEX'
GROUP BY ti.tester_name
ORDER BY ti.tester_name
```

I have added just two fields, you can add according to your need.

Comment: Thanks, and btw I made a little change `MAX(ti.last_checked)`, and `GROUP BY` before `ORDER BY`.

Comment: I just found a flaw in this. I actually wanted to grab the row corresponding the the latest timestamp. However this just displays the latest time stamp as a new column.